# SAXParseException After Upgraded to Spring 4.1.1

Tags: spring, hibernate

Below is the error I am getting after upgrade to spring.

```
    Caused by: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
     Line 20 in XML document from class path resource [dataStoreContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is     
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'local' is not allowed to appear in element 'ref'.
```

**The Hibernate version I am using is  3.0**

Below is my context xml  using

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc        
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

       <bean id="dataSource"    
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
         <property name="jndiName">
        <value>cdqiDS</value>
        </property>
       </bean>

           <bean id="sessionFactory"  
       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
        <ref local="dataSource"/>
            </property>
            <property name="mappingResources">
                </property>
```

Edit 1: After changing the local as bean i am  getting the below error

```
   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
  instantiate bean class
       [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]:
   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
  resource [dataStoreContext.xml]: 
    Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/LobHandler
```

Comment: @Jens can I use as below  <ref bean="dataSource"/>

Comment: @ M. Deinum any idea about the issue  I am getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `org.springframework.jdbc.jar` to your classpath.

Comment: Added the updated spring-jdbc jar to the class path the issue is resolved thanks